# Why is 2 ** (1 << 31) == 0?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Running this in node REPL, gives me:

```
> 2 ** (1 << 31)
0
```

I also wrote a small algorithm for this, which gives me 1.

```js
function pow(x, n) {
    let res = 1;
    let invert = false;
    if (n < 0) { invert = true; n = -n; };

    while (n > 0) {
        if (n & 1)
            res = res * x;
        n = n >> 1; // n / 2
        x = x * x;
    }

    if (invert) { 
        res = 1 / res;
    }
    return res;
};
```

Questions:

1. Why is the actual answer in the REPL 0?
2. Is there anything wrong in my algorithm above?

Comment: The actual result is *so small* that JS cannot express it as a fraction, hence you get zero.

Comment: Bitwise operators work on signed 32-bit integers in JavaScript, thus 1<<31 wraps around to -2147483648. Raising 2 to that power is so small it's expressed as 0.

Comment: I don't understand, why people don't even do the effort of typing `1 << 31` into their console, so they'd notice what the problem is. Instead they ask, if their algorithm is correct, that gives them `1`, for `2 ** (-2147483648)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value `1 << 31` is a *negative* number with a large magnitude, much larger than can be represented with standard floating point representations. Thus 0 is about as close as you can get to the actual value.

Floating point computer math is a surprisingly complicated subject. It's not exactly magic but it's pretty involved. Some languages provide some sort of "fixed point" decimal math system that allows for unlimited precision at the expense of computational efficiency. JavaScript has no such built-in facility.

As to the iterative algorithm, what happens is that when you flip the negative value back to positive, it's too big to fit in an integer. The first time the `>>` in the loop happens, you end up with a negative exponent again because JavaScript bitwise operators force an internal conversion to 32-bit signed integer. If you shift with `>>>` instead, you wont have that problem.

Comment: Even [WolframAlpha doesn't want to give me the actual value of this...](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+%5E+-2147483648)

Comment: Right, it's 1 over 2 to the 2 billionth power, which even for purposes of sending a space probe to Alpha Centauri is still pretty much zero.

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on how to fix the algorithm above, though?

Comment: @quarkstone you cannot "fix" it with ordinary numerics in JavaScript. You'd have to find some other way of dealing with it.

Comment: @Pointy, actually, what's wrong with the above example is the arithmetic shift. Converting that into logical seems to provide the correct result as long as the input covered in 32 bit.

Comment: @quarkstone I don't know what you mean by "converting that into logical".  What did you come up with?

Comment: Replacing the line `n = n >> 1` which has the arithmetic shift with a logical shift, i.e, `n = n >>> 1` or alternatively for handling over 32 to 53 bits `n = n / 2`,  seems to fix the above.

Comment: Ah right, if you use `>>>`. I'll add that to the answer so it's easier for any potential future reader to notice.